# Invalid Credentials for bing maps in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, bing-maps

Impossible to display the map. I still have a error message:
*"Invalid Credentials. Sign up for a developer account at: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers"*

However, I created a account correctly and obtained a valid key:

- Application name: Geography
- Key: **My key**
- Application Url:
- Key type: Basic / Dev/Test
- Created date: 08/12/2015
- Expiration date: None

My xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="Geography.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <m:Map CredentialsProvider="*My key*">
        </m:Map>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a proxy whose I ignore the existence.

So, I set the following config in my app.config file and the error message no longer appears:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
    <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://ProxyAddress:Port"/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Comment: I had same issue but when using a VPN.  Microsoft should really point this out in their documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
<Window x:Class="Geography.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
    Title="Maps" Height="350" Width="525" Style="{StaticResource OfficeStyle}">
    <Grid>
    <m:Map CredentialsProvider="/*YOUR ID*/" x:Name="myMap" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then add it into cs code

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows;
   using System.Windows.Controls;
   using System.Windows.Data;
   using System.Windows.Documents;
   using System.Windows.Input;
   using System.Windows.Media;
   using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
   using System.Windows.Shapes;
   using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;
   namespace Geography
   {
         /// <summary>
         /// Interaction logic for Maps.xaml
         /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
               InitializeComponent();
               myMap.Focus();
               //Set map to Aerial mode with labels
               myMap.Mode = new AerialMode();
            }
        }
    }
```

go following link to get more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830433.aspx

Comment: Now it is the problem of YOUR ID. check it first.

Comment: How to check the key ? I see nothing which fails on the website https://www.bingmapsportal.com when I connect to it with my login.

Comment: Who can give me a valid key to try ?

Comment: Go to the following link to get more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830433.aspx