# How to fix 'Invalid Credentials - Sign up for a Developer Account' when behind a VPN

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I am trying to get the Bing Maps WPF control running in my WPF Application (connecting to the Internet through a VPN). I've already created a working API Key.

I've already tried the answer from [Invalid Credentials for bing maps in wpf application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981578/invalid-credentials-for-bing-maps-in-wpf-application) - which doesn't work, because I use a VPN (or at least that's what I understood).

```
<Grid>
     <m1:Map CredentialsProvider="YOUR_KEY" Mode="AerialWithLabels"/>
</Grid>
```

I've read the BingMaps WPF Control Documentation and followed their basics tutorial. If NordVPN is turned on the authentication fails.

My problem is that any time my VPN (NordVPN) is turned on, the Authentication fails and the popup saying "Invalid Credentials. Sign up for a developer account at ..." shows up. If I turn my VPN off, it works perfectly fine. I think it has to do with the VPN behaving similar to a proxy and failing the authentication. With a normal proxy I could fix the problem using the proxy settings in the appconfig. As this is not a proxy but a vpn you connect to through a proprietary application, this does not work (or at least I don't know how to get it to work).

Comment: I've also tried this: https://entwickler-forum.de/forum/net-und-windows/vb/75743-nochmal-bingmaps-wpf-control - Warning: It's in German

Comment: Have you verified that the VPN is not blocking specific outbound requests, or modifying what you send over the wire?

Comment: I hav indeed not done that. I'll try it now.

Comment: You were correct. It was indeed blocking outbound requests. Turning off their CyberSec feature fixed the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Den Delimarsky already answered, NordVPN blocked swome of the outbound requests. This happens when you turn on the CyberSec feature, which appears to have flagged certain Microsoft sites as suspicious. Turning CyberSec off fixes the problem.

A big thank you to Den Delimarsky for his help!